# How to set value of the input when I use select option? Java script with if

Tags: javascript, select, if-statement, input

I have following scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="UTF-8">
        <SCRIPT src="scripts2.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM>
            <SELECT name="receipt" onchange="set_input_value()">
                <OPTION id="P" value="P">P / </OPTION>
                <OPTION id="b" value="b">b / </OPTION>
            </SELECT>
            <INPUT type='text' id='id1' />
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and

```
function set_input_value(){
    if(document.getElementById('P').value=='P'){
        document.getElementById('id1').value='1';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('b').value=='b'){
        document.getElementById('id1').value='2';
    }
}
```

I want to make something like. If I choose option 'P' set the value of the input on 1. If I choose option 'b' set the value of the input on 2.

Sorry, if it has been solved somewhere, but I didn't find it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Should be tagged `javascript` and not `java`.

Comment: You should correct your function name to a more acceptable one too: set_input_value() -> setInputValue()

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc How is `set_input_value` bad?  Looks like a style decision, to me.  It has no impact on how it works.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein He sure has the right to have his own naming style, but one should try to follow the coding conventions of the used language as much as possible, the same way I cAn DeCiDe To WrItE lIkE tHiS iF I wAnT, bUt It WiLl LoOk AwKwArD!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the value of the SELECT element.  You are getting the OPTION element by id and checking its value.  Change it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="UTF-8">
        <SCRIPT src="scripts2.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT type='text/javascript'>
    function set_input_value(){
        if(document.getElementById('receipt').value=='P'){
            document.getElementById('id1').value='1';
        }
        if(document.getElementById('receipt').value=='b'){
            document.getElementById('id1').value='2';
        }
    }
    </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <FORM>
            <SELECT id='receipt' name="receipt" onchange="set_input_value()">
                <OPTION id="P" value="P">P / </OPTION>
                <OPTION id="b" value="b">b / </OPTION>
            </SELECT>
        <INPUT type='text' id='id1' />
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your markup cleaner by creating event handlers completely in JavaScript, you can also make use of `this` to find the currently selected `value`. You should be giving an ID to your `select` element and not the `option` children:

```
<select id="receipt">

document.getElementById("receipt").onchange = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('id1');
    // You could do this.  The select box will take on the selected option's value:
    // var value = document.getElementById("receipt").value;
    // but since `this` already is the select box, you can just do it this way:
    var value = this.value;

    if (value == "b")
        input.value = 2;
}
```

Comment: I tweaked your code with some comments.  If that was rude or offensive, feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the suggest using jQuery.
I put all code.

HTML + JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>StackTest</title>        
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        function changeValue(valor) {
            if(valor == 'P') {
                $('#text1').val('1');
            } else if (valor == 'b') {
                $('#text1').val('2');
            } else {
                $('#text1').val('');
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <select id="combo" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="P">P /</option>
            <option value="b">b /</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="text1" />
    </body>
</html>
```